# What is the difference between a dollar sign and a dollar sign followed by a period in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In jQuery, what is the difference between `$`  and `$.`? Please provide a practical explanation if possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`$` is a reference (or synonym, if you want an analogy) to the global `jQuery` object. `$.<method>` calls a static method of the `jQuery` object, where `$(<selector>)` creates a new instance of the `jQuery` object.

Answer (score 2):

In the context of jQuery, `$` refers to the global `jQuery` [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects).

`$.` by itself is invalid JavaScript. As `$` is an [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects), methods on this object are called like on any other object: `$.methodname()`.

Maybe it becomes clearer by substituting `$` with `jQuery`: `jQuery.methodname()`.

Answer (score 2):

I presume you are asking about the syntactic difference between `$('#selector');` and `$.parseJSON(str);`.

The former is an invocation of a function called `$` and the latter invokes it's method called `parseJSON`. Yup, functions can have methods - it is possible because Javascript functions are also objects. Figuratively speaking:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function $(str) {
   alert(str);
}

$.parseJSON = function () {
   alert('Parsing JSON');
}

$('Hi');
$.parseJSON('{}');


</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery:

> the $ function, which is a factory
>   method for the jQuery object. These
>   functions, often called commands, are
>   chainable; they each return a jQuery
>   object
>
> $.-prefixed functions. These are
>   utility functions which do not work on
>   the jQuery object per se.
>
> Typically, access to and manipulation
>   of multiple DOM nodes begins with the
>   $ function being called with a CSS
>   selector string, which results in a
>   jQuery object referencing matching
>   elements in the HTML page. This node
>   set can be manipulated by calling
>   instance methods on the jQuery object,
>   or on the nodes themselves. For
>   example:
>
> ```
> $("div.test").add("p.quote").addClass("blue").slideDown("slow");
> ```
>
> This line finds the union of all div
>   tags with class attribute test and all
>   p tags with CSS class attribute quote,
>   adds the class attribute blue to each
>   matched element, and then slides them
>   down with an animation. The $ and add
>   functions affect the matched set,
>   while the addClass and slideDown
>   affect the referenced nodes.
>
> The methods prefixed with $. are
>   convenience methods or affect global
>   properties and behaviour. For example,
>   the following is an example of the map
>   function called each in jQuery:
>
> ```
> $.each([1,2,3], function(){  
> document.write(this + 1); });
> ```
>
> This writes the number 234 to the
>   document.

Answer (score 1):

`$` - dollar sign is also same as Jquery usage. But I preferred to use dollar sign because I like the way dollar sign is.

Comment: The question is about the difference between `$` and `$.`, not `$` and `jQuery`.